# PostMessage demo code for Trusted Web Activity doesn't work

Tags: android, trusted-web-activity

Following this article - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/post-message-twa - I have tried the demo code for PostMessage and it doesn't work (the reference demo code is here - https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/tree/main/demos/twa-post-message).
Could you, please, help me to find out why is the demo not working and how to fix it?
Thank you!

I have implemented the TWA PostMessage demo code in my demo application but the `result` parameter of `onRelationshipValidationResult` is always false therefore `onMessageChannelReady` is never called.